# How to substring and get previous character

Tags: java, substring

I'm still very new to java and I search to replace a part of a string by another, except if the previous character of this string is C,V,M,G or W.  I.e. if I get `BILLE` as input I want the output give me `B.Y.E` but if I get `MILLE` as input, I want `MILLE` as output.

Here what I've tried :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class Phaille {
    static Map<String, String> phaille2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        phaille2.put("ILL", ".Y.");
    }

    public static String phaille1(final String tampon){
        int position= tampon.indexOf("ILL");
        String sub=tampon.substring(position,tampon.length());


        if (position != -1 ){
            if(!(sub.endsWith("C"))){
                return phaille2.get(tampon);
            }

        }
        return tampon;
    }
}
```

But when i test with `"CYRILLE"`, `"CECILLE"`,`"ILL"`,`"CILLILLILL"`, the test gives to me

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<null> but was:<"CYR.Y.E">.
```

Comment: The error message is jUnit related, so I guess your problem lies in your test method and not in the code you posted, as it produces the correct result `CYR.Y.E`, but jUnit expects it to be a null value apparently. Check if your assertion logic is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit test output is a bit confusing (it should probably reverse the order of comparison to make the message reasonable). But basically, what it says is that you are returning `null` instead of returning `CYR.Y.E`.

You are returning `null` because of this line:

```
            return phaille2.get(tampon);
```

Your `tampon` is the original string `CYRILLE`. There is no item in `phaille2` that matches the key `CYRILLE` (there is only an item for `ILL`), so the `HashMap` returns `null`, and this is what you return.

What you are doing is:

- Looking for the position of `ILL` (that's good).
- Finding the substring of `tabmpon` from that position *forward* (why? This will give you `ILLE`).
- Checking to see if it begins with `C` (it will not, because it will always begin with `ILL` because that's what you were searching).
- Returning the key based on `tampon` which I already told you does not exist in the hash table.

What you should do:

- Find the position of the `ILL` as you do.
- If the position is 0, replace `ILL` with what the `HashTable` contains for `"ILL"` (*not* `tampon`).

  - You should take the substring of `tampon` from before the position of `ILL` that you found,
  - Then add the replacement you got from the `HashTable`
  - Then add the substring of `tampon` from *after* the `ILL`.

  You'll probably need to play with this a bit to get the numbers right.
- If the position is -1, there is no `ILL` in the number, and you need to return `tampon` as it is.
- If the position is positive, look what is in the `tampon.charAt(position-1)`, and decide whether you need to replace `ILL` (as I described above) or not.

I advise *against* using a regular expression, as I don't think it was taught at this point of your class, and it seems from your question that you are supposed to solve this with `substring`.

Comment: I am supposed to solve this like i can i just prefer using substring (regex ar a bit dark for me). But i admit i've got a bit problem with "ou should take the substring of tampon from before the position of ILL that you found, then the replacement, then the substring of tampon from after the ILL. You'll probably need to play with this a bit to get the numbers right."

Comment: This is the learning part. You need to figure out how to get a substring *from the start to a given position*, and a substrinf *from a given position to the end*. Then it's just a matter of returning `x + (replacement) + y`. I believe that if you don't experiment with this yourself, even in another class, until you get a feel for what `indexOf` and `substring` return, you won't understand Strings properly.

Comment: I'm aggred with you i need to do it from myself to learn it. If i figure by myself how it's work or where is the problem I think i will be a better programmer. Thanks you RealSkeptic for this huge answer and for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "BILLE";
    String s2 = "MILLE";
    String pattern = "(?<![WCVMG])ILL";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(pattern, ".Y."));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(pattern, ".Y."));
    System.out.println("CYRILLE".replaceAll(pattern, ".Y."));
    System.out.println("CILLILLILL".replaceAll(pattern, ".Y."));
}
```

O/P :

```
B.Y.E
MILLE
CYR.Y.E
CILL.Y..Y.
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks you very much ;) Juste have to put this as generic class ;)

Comment: You're missing 'W' :-)

Comment: @NatsuMiko - You are wc :)